# thread program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" while finding the sum of a column in sqlite in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

i have written a function to find the total expense and todays expense from the table created in sqlite. here is my code

```
-(void) calculateTodaysExp    
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];    
    sqlite3_stmt *statement1;    
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)    
    {
        NSString *todays = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT sum(amount) FROM expenseDetails WHERE date = \"%@\"", dateString];    
        const char *todays_statement = [todays UTF8String];    
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(expenseDB, todays_statement, -1, &statement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement1) == SQLITE_ROW)    
            {
                NSString *todaysExpenseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:    (const char *)sqlite3_column_int(statement1, 0)];    
                todaysExpense.text = todaysExpenseString;     

            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement1);    
        sqlite3_close(expenseDB);    
    }
}

-(void) calculateTotalExp    
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];    
    sqlite3_stmt *statement2;    
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)    
    {
        NSString *total = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SUM(amount) FROM expenseDetails"];    

        const char *total_statement = [total UTF8String];    
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(expenseDB, total_statement, -1, &statement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement2) == SQLITE_ROW)    
            {
                NSString *totalExpenseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_int64(statement2, 0)];    
                totalExpense.text = totalExpenseString;    
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement2);    
        sqlite3_close(expenseDB);    
    }
}
```

wherever i try to call these functions the program stops and shows "program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" ". if anyone could find a fix for this. thanks in advance

here is my entire code

```
#import "sqliteViewController.h"

@implementation sqliteViewController
@synthesize selectCategory = _selectCategory;
@synthesize enterExpense;
@synthesize dateString;
@synthesize showDate;
@synthesize moneyLeft;
@synthesize todaysExpense;
@synthesize totalExpense;
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *docsDirectory;
    NSArray *directoryPaths;
    directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"expense.db"]];
    NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([fileMan fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errorMessage;
            const char *sqlStatement = "create table if not exists expenseDetails (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CATEGORY TEXT, AMOUNT FLOAT, DATE TEXT)";
            if (sqlite3_exec(expenseDB, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"failed to create table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(expenseDB);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"failed to open/create");
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[ NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YY"];
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"date%@", dateString);
    showDate.text = dateString;
    [self calculateTodaysExp];
    [self calculateTotalExp];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(IBAction)categorySave:(id)sender {
    _selectCategory = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"close" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"food",@"transportation",@"fuel",@"mobile",@"shopping", nil];
    [_selectCategory showInView:self.view];
}
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:  (NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        categoryBuffer = @"food";
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        categoryBuffer = @"transportation";
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        categoryBuffer = @"fuel";
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 3)
    {
        categoryBuffer = @"mobile";
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 4)
    {
        categoryBuffer = @"shopping";
    }
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertExpense = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO expenseDetails (category, amount, date) Values (\"%@\", \"%d\", \"%@\")", categoryBuffer, enterExpense.text, dateString];
        const char *insert_statement = [insertExpense UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(expenseDB, insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            enterExpense.text = @"";
            [self calculateTodaysExp];
            [self calculateTotalExp];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"failed");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(expenseDB);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to insert in table");
    }
}
-(void) calculateTodaysExp
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement1;
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *todays = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT TOTAL(amount) FROM expenseDetails WHERE date = \"%@\"", dateString];
        const char *todays_statement = [todays UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(expenseDB, todays_statement, -1, &statement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement1) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                int result = sqlite3_column_int(statement1,0);
                NSString *todaysExpenseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
                todaysExpense.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement1);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"failed to select");
        }
        sqlite3_close(expenseDB);
    }
}
-(void) calculateTotalExp
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement2;
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *total = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SUM(amount) FROM expenseDetails"];

        const char *total_statement = [total UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(expenseDB, total_statement, -1, &statement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement2) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                int result1 = sqlite3_column_int(statement2,0);
                NSString *totalExpenseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result1];
                totalExpense.text = totalExpenseString;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement2);
        }
        sqlite3_close(expenseDB);
    }
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [enterExpense resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Comment: Single step through this routine in the debugger and figure out what line is causing the exception. Or sometimes using an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) is very effective. No need to be guessing. Also, check that `databasePath` and `dateString` are non-`nil`. Unrelated, but (a) `sqlite3_finalize` statements should go inside the `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2()...)` blocks (don't finalize a statement that wasn't prepared); and (b) show `sqlite3_errmsg` in `else` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `sqlite3_column_int` and creating a string, e.g.:

```
NSString *todaysExpenseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:    (const char *)sqlite3_column_int(statement1, 0)];
```

That's not valid. You're casting it as a `(const char *)`, but it's not a string, but rather an integer. You really need to:

```
int result = sqlite3_column_int(statement1, 0);
NSString *todaysExpenseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
```

Comment: thankyou that worked. now the program runs, but when i print the value obtained in that functions in a label its printing a very big value. its actually an expense manager showing current days expense as well as total expense till date.

Comment: @ArunKumar It's hard to say without seeing your database and looking at the data. I'd try confirming whether the SQL is right by trying your SQL in the simulator's database (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/...) using your preferred Mac database tool (you can use `sqlite3` command line tool; I use [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/); many people use a browser based SQLite tool). That isolates whether the issue is a SQL/data issue, or an iOS programming issue.

Comment: i am new to this programming field and to this website as well. actually i created database within the xcode, i do not know how to check the database details. i have the entire code with me now how can i paste it here for your reference? if you could help me please. thanks in advance and thank you very much for your response.

Comment: @ArunKumar You can compress your project and upload the zip file somewhere (e.g. Dropbox or whatever) and then post a link to it here. But my little trick in my above comment works for databases created by the app in the simulator (the simulator's folders are inside that folder on your computer). That directory is where iOS keeps the apps and, for each app, the `Documents` folder for the respective apps.

Comment: i have updated my question with my entire code. thank you once again for your response

Comment: @ArunKumar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27502/discussion-between-rob-and-arun-kumar)

Comment: @ArunKumar I suspect that your issue stems from the fact that you're storing expense amount values in your database as strings, not as numeric values. In the process of cleaning up the code (see the chat), I made sure that the numeric values were being store as `double` values, and everything seems to work absolutely fine.